# Framebufferobject crashes when I do pop without resetting the framebuffer to the original

Tags: c++, opengl

```
glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fboId);
gl::drawFilled(mesh_);
//glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);

glAssert();
glPopAttrib();
glAssert(); // <= crashes here
```

If I uncomment the line `//glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);` it works, how come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suppose the FBO manages some of its own state (there are some pushed/popped states whose values depend on the framebuffer binding) and it gets somehow messed up when you pop these and the framebuffer has suddenly changed. Maybe it's a driver fault where they didn't integrate the FBOs correctly with the rare case of intermediate state pushes/pops (which are quite old and deprecated anyway).

But don't use `glPush/glPopAttrib` anyway, it's quite slow, as you surely don't need to push **every** state. Don't do that just out of laziness.